# How to start/resume Windows Phone 8.1 C# app upon incoming push notification

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a pilot Windows Runtime app on WP 8.1 which must show some overlay (or at least MessageDialog) to the user on incoming push notifications.

The code below shows the message when the app is in the foreground and toast is coming, but I can't find how to start/resume/do_whatever the app, when it is in background or may be app wasn't even started at all or the phone is locked.
Atm I see in the console log, that toast is still received when the app goes background, but no UI message appears.

What I have:

`ToastCapable="true"`  in the appxmanifest.

In some xaml.cs file:

```
init() {
    PushNotificationChannel channel 
        = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
    channel.PushNotificationReceived += OnPushNotificationReceived;
}

void OnPushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs e) {
    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
        showToTheUser();
    });
}

private async void showToTheUser() {
    // TODO message to be replaced with full-screen overlay later

    var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Incoming push");

    messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(
        "Accept",
        new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CommandInvokedHandler)));
    messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(
        "Refuse",
        new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CommandInvokedHandler)));

    messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
    messageDialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;

    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
}

private void CommandInvokedHandler(IUICommand command) {
    if (command.Label.Equals("Accept")) {
        // show some UI page of the app
    }
}
```

I'm a seasoned Java guy and just started with WP and C#, so I'm pretty confused what would be the right way to do it all on WP or what I should search for.

Comment: It's not possible. Image if apps could just open themselves for any reason. It would be very annoying.

Comment: Ok, what Viber does? You make a call and it shows the overlay with incoming caller name and photo and buttons Answer, Reject and I don't know if this is native or just very similar to the native message, but I want it the same way. And when you Accept it starts the app.

I don't want to start the full app right away, just display a screen with a text and 2 buttons. If it simplifies anything.

Comment: What I also noticed - in Settings/notifications + actions  I see both Viber and WhatsUp, who asked during installation for permission to receive push notifications. However, my app is not listed there. May be it is connected to the problem somehow, i.e. I might need to request special permission to resume app upon push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to start the app based on push notification and show info.. That is not possible on the Windows Phone. User can click on the notification banner and open the app, but you cannot automatically do it.

Comment: Can I display anything with a text and 2 buttons? And only then start the app upon user click?
Or I am restricted to usual toast, tile and badge notifications where I can have only text and may be an icon?

Comment: What I also noticed - in Settings/notifications + actions  I see both Viber and WhatsUp, who asked during installation for permission to receive push notifications. However, my app is not listed there. May be it is connected to the problem somehow, i.e. I might need to request special permission to resume app upon push?